# How do I read only specific columns from a JSON dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON dataframe with 12 columns, however, I only want to read columns 2 and 5 which are named "name" and "score."

Currently, the code I have is:

```py
df = pd.read_json("path",orient='columns', lines=True)

print(df.head())
```

What that does is displays every column, as would be expected.

After reading through the documentation here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

I can't find any real way to only parse certain columns within json, compared to csv where you can parse columns using names=[]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting multiple columns R vs python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576519/selecting-multiple-columns-r-vs-python-pandas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pass a list of columns for indexing

```
df[["name","score"]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going insane over such a simple problem!